# How to remove a WordPress action which uses the current object - &$this - [WCFM-Ask a Question button]?

Tags: wordpress, class, hook

I'm new to php and I try modifying a Wordpress website with Woocommerce and WCFM multivendor plugin. Any help would be very helpful :)

I'm trying to remove the "Ask a Question" button added by WCFM plugin (which does not appear at the correct spot).

I tried to use the remove function with the correct class, but I can't make it to work.

I tried to add this piece of code in the functions.php file of my child theme :

```
global $WCFM;
remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', array( $WCFM->wcfm_enquiry, 'wcfm_enquiry_button'),15);
```

and this :

```
global $wcfm_enquiry;
remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', array( $wcfm_enquiry, 'wcfm_enquiry_button'),15);
```

or this:

```
global $WCFM;
$wcfm_enquiry =  $WCFM->wcfm_enquiry;
remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', array( $wcfm_enquiry, 'wcfm_enquiry_button'),15);
```

In WCFM plugin, the add function is inside the WCFM_Enquiry class :

```
class WCFM_Enquiry {
    
    public $wcfm_myaccount_inquiry_endpoint = 'inquiry';
    public $wcfm_myaccount_view_inquiry_endpoint = 'view-inquiry';

    public function __construct() {
        global $WCFM;
       (...)
       add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary',    array( &$this, 'wcfm_enquiry_button' ), 15 );
```

This class is initialized inside the WFCM class :

```
class WCFM {
    (...)
        // Load Enquiry Module
        if (apply_filters('wcfm_is_pref_enquiry', true)) {
            if (!is_admin() || defined('DOING_AJAX') || defined('WCFM_REST_API_CALL') || (isset($_REQUEST['action']) && $_REQUEST['action'] == 'elementor')) {
                $this->load_class('enquiry');
                $this->wcfm_enquiry = new WCFM_Enquiry();
            }
        }
```

This WCFM class is initialized in :

```
    if(!class_exists('WCFM')) {
        include_once( 'core/class-wcfm.php' );
        global $WCFM, $WCFM_Query;
        $WCFM = new WCFM( __FILE__ );
        $GLOBALS['WCFM'] = $WCFM;
        
        // Init WCFM Query
        include_once( 'core/class-wcfm-query.php' );
        $WCFM_Query = new WCFM_Query();
        $GLOBALS['WCFM_Query'] = $WCFM_Query;
```

Would you have any idea why my code doesn't work?

Thank you very much, I'm a bit lost with this !

Aurélien

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to add an action which includes a remove action.

```
add_action('init',function(){
    global $WCFM, $WCFMmp;
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary',    array( $WCFM->wcfm_enquiry, 'wcfm_enquiry_button' ), 15 );
});
```

I have not quite understood why it is necessary but it does work.